# Amazon SQS - Communicating URL between servers

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, command-line, amazon-sqs

I was wondering if I could get some help with Amazon SQS. In my example I am trying to set up a queue on Server A and query it from Server B. The issue I’m having is that when I create a queue on server A it provides me with a URL like this:

```
https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/599169622985/test-topic-queue
```

Then on my other server I apparently need to query this URL for information on the queue. The trouble is, my server B doesn’t know the URL that I created on server A. This seems like a bit of a flaw, do I really need to find a way to also communicate the URL to server B before it can connect to the queue, and if so, does anyone have any good solutions for this?

I have tried asking on Amazon and didn’t get any replies.

Comment: This is not a flaw. Generally your queue will be defined ahead of time as to what kind of messages it will have and what will publish to it and read from it. Dynamically creating queues is not usually how a message queue is used at least not without a mechanism to publish the new queue.

Comment: Thank you for the reply @datasage. The problem is, I can define the "test-topic-queue" as a known but I wont know the rest of the URL on the second server, i.e "https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/599169622985". Are you saying I should just create a queue before hand and keep this URL, then store it as a variable on both servers?

Comment: Yeah, create the queue before hand and configure it on both servers. Or put it somewhere were both servers can check for it.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the "put it somewhere where both servers can check for it?". Also perhaps put it in an answer so I can award it to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sure servers A and B must share some kind of information regarding the queue. If not the full URL, you can just share the name, and retrieve the queue URL on server B using the GetQueueUrl API endpoint:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/Query_QueryGetQueueUrl.html

Comment: Ah thank you for that, that's perfect. I am using this with Amazon-CLI, are you able to tell me if this command exists for that because I can't seem to find it :(

Comment: I never used CLI for that, but indeed it seems it's not supported, at least not documented.

Answer (score 1):

Queues should be treated like any other resources (cache, datastores, etc) and defined ahead of time in some type of application configuration file.

If your use case involves queue end points that change on a regular basis, then you might want to store the queue endpoint in something that both instances can check. It could be a database, or it could be a config file pulled from s3.